# scrollable dialog breaks background flex-grow

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, flexbox

I have a simple page like

```
<main>
    <header>Header</header>
    <section>Content</section>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</main>
<dialog>Dialog</dialog>
```

CSS:

```
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
section {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
...
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/430prach/1/)

The `section` fills the whole screen (vertically) and the footer is visible at the bottom.

This layout also works when the `section` is bigger (higher) that the height of the window

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/430prach/2/)

Now you can scroll, and the footer is still at the bottom.

BUT, if we have a modal dialog which is also bigger than the screen, all this doesn't seem to work anymore

[SCROLL DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/430prach/)

If you scroll to the bottom you can see that the footer is not at the bottom anymore. Can this be fixed ? Or is there a nice solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `dialog{ max-height: 100%}`

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/430prach/4/)

Comment: Your solution does indeed work. I noticed however that I had an absolute positioned dialog [jsfiddle])http://jsfiddle.net/430prach/6/ In this case it doesn't work. Any suggestions if this could be fixed too ?

Comment: It does work for me. see this  - http://jsfiddle.net/430prach/7/

well, the <dialog> element has its default attribute "absolute". The browser will automatically position the dialog in the center of the viewport. You can override this behaviour using the top, bottom, left and right properties if desired.

The height is also set by default as  -webkit-fit-content

ie, element's height is defined by its content and will not automatically size to fill its containing block.

So, I guess this is causing the problem. so I set max-height: 100%; which did the job. Sorry If I'm wrong. thanks